# JavaScript if else condition confusion

Tags: javascript

I have below code

```
if (gridObj.INVOICEORDERNUMBER) {
  if (!cancelledStatus.length && !withDrawn.length) {
    this.gridCmp.editValidation = true;
    this.errorMessage = ErrorMessage.OpenOrderMsg;
  } else {
    this.relatedLicenses = false;
    this.hasDRLPLicense = false;
    this.deletePopupMsg = ErrorMessage.DeletePopupMsg;
    this.showDeletePopup = true;
  }
} else if (this.hasDRLPLicense) {
  this.gridCmp.editValidation = true;
  this.errorMessage2 = ErrorMessage.DRLPLicenseDeleteMsg;
} else {
  this.relatedLicenses = false;
  this.hasDRLPLicense = false;
  this.deletePopupMsg = ErrorMessage.DeletePopupMsg;
  this.showDeletePopup = true;
}
```

Here I need to check whether both `if` conditions satisfy or not. With the current approach, I can only check anyone if condition, as it is an `if-else`, `if` statement.

What I need to achieve here is

1. If first `if` condition is satisfied -> `show errorMessage`
2. If second `if` condition (else if) satisfied -> `show errorMessage2`
3. If both satisfied -> `show both errorMessage and errorMessage2`
4. If none satisfied -> `execute else`

This might be a stupid question, but my brain is not working any more today. Please help. Thanks

Comment: what is the *other* condition? i see three ifs.

Comment: Move 3 up to 1, and move original 1 and 2 down.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the logic you explained, this is the truth table you are looking for:

```
cond1 | cond2 | errorMessage | errorMessage2 | execute 
------+-------+--------------+---------------+--------
false | false |  NO          |  NO           |  YES
false | true  |  NO          |  YES          |  NO
true  | false |  YES         |  NO           |  NO
true  | true  |  YES         |  YES          |  NO
```

This is the code which will accomplish it:

```
if (cond1 || cond2) {
  if (cond1) { 
    // show errorMessage
  }

  if (cond2) { 
    // show errorMessage2
  }
} else {
  // execute ...
}
```

Comment: @ManasKhandelwal maybe you should be a bit more conservative with your -1s. He's correct. This is precisely what OP describes in his 4 points.

Comment: @Dropout My bad .

Comment: Thanks @Dropout. Lately it became a fashion to give -1s too fast :-(

Comment: Thanks Man, you saved my day.. now I can have some sleep :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.

```
if (gridObj.INVOICEORDERNUMBER || this.hasDRLPLicense) {
  this.gridCmp.editValidation = true;

  if (gridObj.INVOICEORDERNUMBER && !cancelledStatus.length && !withDrawn.length) {  
    this.errorMessage = ErrorMessage.OpenOrderMsg;
  }
  if (this.hasDRLPLicense) {
    this.errorMessage2 = ErrorMessage.DRLPLicenseDeleteMsg;
  }
} else {
    this.relatedLicenses = false;
    this.hasDRLPLicense = false;
    this.deletePopupMsg = ErrorMessage.DeletePopupMsg;
    this.showDeletePopup = true;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Tatul for the help!